# Directus many-to-many display template not showing up

Tags: directus

I'm not sure *where* **Display Template** option is supposed to show up on M2M relationships.

Here on `movies` collection setting up `genres`:

[image: Relation]

and the options

[image]

[Docs](https://docs.directus.io/guides/relationships.html#many-to-many) seems confusing about the distinction between Visible Columns and Display Template:

> **Visible Columns** sets the columns the interface shows (we're using `name`)
>
> **Display Template** sets the columns the interface shows (we're using `{{movie.name}}`)

Visible Columns does the above; in this example shows the `title` column in edit page for `genres`:

[image]

Alright, great!

But what about the template? maybe in the collection list?

no, just the count:

[image]

I've tried all these templates but nothing shows up anywhere:

- `{{title}}`
- `{{movie.title}}`
- `{{genre.title}}`
- `{{genres.genre.title}}`

What is the correct template here? Where is Display Template supposed to show up?

My collections setup:

```
movies
 title text,
 genres M2M (alias)

genres
 title text

movies_genres
 id pk,
 genre numeric,
 movie numeric
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This applies to O2M Interfaces:

Since there can be more than one related item linked, in the items list, the display template is rendered as a number of items until you interact with the item...

If you place your mouse over the **Genres Fields**, you should see the display template rendered.

A **popover** should show up and display the list of items as you defined.

Comment: Correct. But as you said it only applies to o2m not m2m. I would've expected the same popover behavior for m2m, but that's not the case.

Comment: I should have been more clear...
O2M interfaces include Many to Many and One to Many.
They cannot be displayed as a list within the table list layout, so they are displayed as a popover.

Comment: I see. But it actually doesn't work as you describe for m2m, while does for o2m. 
Check this out: Go to [demo app -> news collection](https://demo.directus.io/admin) and add a few related news and see if any popover shows up.